# Can we use this system for feature requests?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will this satisfy the need for a feature request system using the "feature_request" tag?

People can subscribe to the feature request RSS with this link:
http://answers.ros.org/feeds/rss/?tags=feature_request

People can vote on features, comment on them, and tag them with other information too. This way, it's all integrated into the current ROS infrastructure, and doesn't clutter ros-users.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39224/can-we-use-this-system-for-feature-requests?/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-07-19**:
I didn't know about the possibility of subscribing to a tag. In that case, I'm OK with it. But it should be documented... maybe in http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @dornhege's response, that this is probably not a good format for doing feature requests.

I think that having both support questions and feature requests in the same area would end up in chaos.

I think that there are a few channels for feature requests already in existence.

- [The REP Process](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0001.html) - Mechanism to propose major feature enhancements to the ROS community.
- [code.ros.org](http://code.ros.org/) - Bug tracker (and feature requests) for core stacks.
- [kforge.ros.org](https://kforge.ros.org/projects/) - Bug trackers for individual stacks and projects.

Finally, if you want to get into the long-term planning of ROS, I strongly encourage you to join one of the [Planning SIGS](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Planning) for determining the direction of development for Groovy and forward.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The askbot-style of answers.ros.org seems to be not that well suited to me. The plus would be that a feature request (as question) can be voted. But comments to that would be posted as answers and as they are resorted depending on votes it might be hard to follow a discussion.

Probably a forum that allows to vote threads is more suited, but if someone would set that up it should obviously integrated with the rest, especially this site, to not confuse everyone.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-07-19**:
Well, it is possible to sort them by newest, but I agree this is definitely a drawback. Is there any way to add an optional comment-thread-like module to askbot?

Another option is to use answers as feature implementations, or links to them, and comments can be made on those with this tool.